# Unable to retrieve system fonts

Tags: photoshop

I am creating a flex panel (myextension) which displays the list of system fonts. I am using the code -"Photoshop.app.fonts"  to retrieve all the installed system fonts.
Everything works fine except in one scenario, which is as follows.
- Open Photoshop.
- Click on File > New. Do not close the "New" dialog.
- Open the extension from Window>Extensions>myextension.

In this case the extension opens but the API "Photoshop.app.fonts" returns null and therefore my panel displays nothing.

Can anyone help me understand why the API returns nothing in this case? How can I overcome this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about the API or a flex panel, but from within Photoshop

```
alert(app.fonts.length)
```

should return the number of fonts installed.